# ui.bootstrap.datepicker manually show select date popup

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm using `ui.bootstrap.datepicker` from https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ page and I'm trying to display the select date popup when pressing another different button. I've tried many things with no success.

Some of the things I've tried :

1. Since the drop-down menu has display:none attribute in the DOM i've tried to make it a block but then different issues come up .. for e.g. you cannot close it when clicking somewhere outside that container.
2. I also tried to manually instantiate it by saying `$('#test').datepicker()` but instantiates the bootstrap datepicker :) and when i try to display it by using the following line of code `$('#test').datepicker("show")` it displays two date popups .. the original ui.bootstrap.datepicker style and the one that originally ships with bootstrap style.
3. I also tried manually trigger the click event on the input box using the `click()` method and `trigger('click')` method from jQuery.

All of these with no success.
So I need help on this.

Comment: Well since the drop-down menu has display:none attribute in the dom i've tried to make it a block but then different issues come up .. for e.g. you cannot close it when clicking somewhere outside. I also tried to manually instantiate it by saying $('#test').datepicker() but instantiates the bootstrap datepicker :) and also manually trigger the click event on the input box using the click() method and trigger('click') method from jQuery

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry :( first time posting question on stackoverflow.... i will know in future..

Comment: You can improve your question afterwards by using the edit link underneath your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is your click() event function in the jquery document ready() function?

Use this code this will do that task.

```
$(function() {
$("#date").datepicker();
$(".trigger").click(function(){ $("#date").datepicker("show"); }); 
});
```

Example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Isakkiraj/s47htk78/

Comment: Hi. thanks for helping me out. I've already tried that example before i'm sorry that i didn't explain it while i was building the question. What it does for me it displays two popups ... one is the original angularjs bootstrap style and the other one is the original bootstrap drop-down style. Keep in mind that i'm using https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ (datepicker) component.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your question.

Comment: I've edited my question... maybe the way its structured now will explain more so that you will understand it better ? When i use your code it displays two popups. One is the original bootstrap style and the other one is the angularjs one. I'm using https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ (datepicker) component.